# How to reference last used column in a certain row and paste certain value in there

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro that loops over a the used range in one sheet (which is the last sheet in the workbook) in a certain column ("H"). The macro should then copy the value, only if it is not 0, and paste it in a sheet called "Overview" in the original row, offset by 3 (e.g. first row becomes 4th row) and in the column behind the last used column in row 5. (I hope that makes sense?). I already worked on some code but I did not manage to reference the last used column correctly and am honestly close to a breakdown.

can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?
This is what I already have:

````
Dim Cell As Range, cRange As Range, lrw As Long
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet
        
        'set worksheets
        With ThisWorkbook
            Set wsSource = .Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
            Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Overview")
        End With
        
    
    LastRow1 = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn1 = wsDestination.Cells(5, "A").End(xlRight).Column
    Set cRange = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(1, 8), wsSource.Cells(LastRow1, 8))
    For Each Cell In cRange.Cells
        If Cell.Value > 0 Then wsDestination.Cells(Cell.Row, LastColumn1).offset(3, 1) = Cell.Value
    Next Cell


End Sub```
````

Comment: Similarly to `LastRow1`, you use `wsDestination.Cells(1, wsDestination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`.

Comment: it gives me an application defined error.... also it needs to be the last used column in the row of A5

Comment: Then use `LastColumn1 = wsDestination.Cells(5, wsDestination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. Note that it is `xlToLeft` and not xlLeft.

Answer (score 0):

### The Subtle Differences in Ways of Finding the 'Last Column'

- To successfully test the first procedure, in a new worksheet you have to:

  - write a value in cell `A1`,
  - write ="" in cell `B1`,
  - write a value in cell `C1`,
  - hide column `C`
  - and use a fill color in cell `D1`.
- The result of the test will be shown in the `Immediate` window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
- The third procedure is an example of how to use the second procedure, the function for calculating the column of the last non-blank cell in a row using the `Find` method.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LastColumnSuptileDifferences()
     
     Dim wb As Workbook
     Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
     
     ' Cell Value Comment
     '  A1:  1    Value
     '  B1:  =""  Formula
     '  C1   1    Value: Hidden Column
     '  D1:       Fill Color
     
     Debug.Print ws.Rows(1).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious).Column ' 3
     Debug.Print ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column        ' 2
     Debug.Print ws.Rows(1).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious).Column   ' 1
     
     Debug.Print ws.Rows(1).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count                    ' 3
     Debug.Print ws.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column        ' 4
     Debug.Print ws.UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns.Count                        ' 4

End Sub

' This will find the last column even if columns are hidden
' unless you set 'excludeEmpties' to 'True'.
' If you set 'excludeEmpties' to 'True', the right-most cells in the row,
' possibly containing a formula that evaluates to "", will be skipped.
' Additionally only the visible cells will be included, i.e. hidden
' right-most columns, possibly containing data in cells of the row,
' will not be considered (mimicking 'End(xlToLeft)' or CRTL+Left).
Function getLastColumnInRow(RowNumber As Variant, _
                            Optional Sheet As Worksheet = Nothing, _
                            Optional excludeEmpties As Boolean = False)
    
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then
        Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
    End If
    
    Dim FormVal As XlFindLookIn
    If excludeEmpties Then
        FormVal = xlValues
    Else
        FormVal = xlFormulas
    End If
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Rows(RowNumber).Find(What:="*", _
                                         LookIn:=FormVal, _
                                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        getLastColumnInRow = rng.Column
    Else
        getLastColumnInRow = 0
    End If
    
End Function

Sub testgetLastColumnInRow()
    '...
    
    LastColumn1 = getLastColumnInRow(5, wsDestination)
    If LastColumn1 = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Data.", vbExclamation, "Empty Row"
        Exit Sub ' or whatever
    End If
    
    ' Continue with code.
    Debug.Print LastColumn1
    
    '...
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

So you didn't quite get the last column right. Here's it back.

````
Dim Cell As Range, cRange As Range, lrw As Long
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet
        
        'set worksheets
        With ThisWorkbook
            Set wsSource = .Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
            Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Overview")
        End With
        
    
    LastRow1 = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn1 = wsDestination.Cells(5, columns.count).End(xltoleft).Column
    Set cRange = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(1, 8), wsSource.Cells(LastRow1, 8))
    For Each Cell In cRange.Cells
        If Cell.Value > 0 Then wsDestination.Cells(Cell.Row, LastColumn1).offset(3, 1) = Cell.Value  
    Next Cell


End Sub```
````